# Handling form data for application/x-www-form-urlencoded contentType

Tags: forms, jsp, servlets, content-type

I have a `textarea` in a jsp page and the contents of that are processed in a Servlet.
I thought the contentType was multipart so I figured I'd use `getFormField()` and `getString()` methods to extract the values but this throws an exception saying

```
the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

When I use `request.getParameter("textAreaID")` it is always null. How do I handle this situation? Any help would be appreciated. Please let me know if the question is not framed in a proper manner before downvoting. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If u want to extract values of many fields,you can use getParameterNames() method

```
       Enumeration paramNames = request.getParameterNames();
       while(paramNames.hasMoreElements())
           {
              String parameter = (String) paramNames.nextElement();
              String parameterValue = (String) request.getParameter(parameter);
              System.out.println("*****" + parameter + " - " + parameterValue);
           }
```